# How to find last updated record id with where condition from hive table

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

How can I count latest userId in hive table whose status is 1? We are inserting incremental data(userId,status,date) in hive on daily basis.
The hive table contains duplicate userId with different date. So I tried a query but got wrong result:

```
select count(t1.userID) 
  from (select userId, 
               max(date) as date 
          from test group by userId) t1 
  join (select userId 
          from test 
         where status=1) t2 
    on t1.userId=t2.userID;
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that should work:

```
SELECT
    T1.USER_ID, 
FROM 
    USER_TABLE T1
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT 
            USER_ID, 
            MAX(UPDATE_DATE) AS MAX_DATE
        FROM 
            USER_TABLE
        GROUP BY USER_ID
    ) T2
    ON T1.USER_ID = T2.USER_ID AND T1.UPDATE_DATE = T2.MAX_DATE
WHERE T1.STATUS = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This work fine but little slow, is there any better option.

SELECT
 COUNT(1)
  from
    (SELECT a.userId, a.date, a.status from test a
    JOIN
    (SELECT userId, max(date) date FROM test GROUP BY userId ) b
    ON (a.userId = b.userId AND a.date = b.date)
    where a.status=1) c;